# Exchange 2013 CU18 upgrade fails due to looking in the wrong place for a file

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange, exchange-2013

I'm installing the CU18 upgrade for Exchange 2013.

Its failing on the UM role bit, because its looking in the wrong place for a file! :(

> ```
> Mailbox role: Unified Messaging service                   FAILED
>  The following error was generated when "$error.Clear();
>       install-MsiPackage -PackagePath $RolePackagePath -LogFile $RoleLogFile Path -UpdatesDir $RoleUpdatesDir -PropertyValues
> ```
>
> ("INSTALLDIR=`"" + $RoleInstall Path + "`" ESE=1");
>           " was run: "Couldn't open package 'D:\en\UMLanguagePack.en-US.msi'. This  installation package could not
>   be opened. Verify that the package exists and th at you can access it,
>   or contact the application vendor to verify that this is a  valid
>   Windows Installer package. Error code is 1619.".
>
> The Exchange Server setup operation didn't complete. More details can
>   be found in ExchangeSetup.log located in the
>   :\ExchangeSetupLogs folder.

There is no D drive on my machine, I have C and E. 
Its a VM, so the installation media is downloaded and isn't an iso, so definately not a D drive.

The file in question resides in E:\Software Install\exchange\en

Is there a way I can fix this and make it look in the right place?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've created a VHD and copied the install files to it, mounted it as D and am trying again... fingers crossed

Answer (score 2):

It's a solution that manually create a folder, and copy related file into this folder.

Besides, we could remove **watermark** from Registry: *HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Exchange server\V15\Unified Messaging*.

> Note: please backup this key first before remove it.

Then, install Exchange by PowerShell:

1. Locate to Exchange installation path. For example: CD: E:\Software Install\exchange
2. Run: Setup.exe /mode:upgrade /IAcceptExchangeServerLicenseTerms